# How to pass object by reference to a constructor

Tags: c++, function, object, reference, constructor

I would like to pass by reference an object to a Contructor, but I get problems, because I don't know how do bound it to the variable of the class.

Here I post some pieces of my code and the error risen.

```
class ShortestPath{
    public:
        ShortestPath(Graph& graph): graph(graph){};[...]
    private:
        Graph *graph; 
};
```

in this case the error risen is:

```
cannot convert `Graph' to `Graph*' in initialization
```

and if I write

```
ShortestPath(Graph& graph): *graph(graph){};[...]
```

the error is

```
expected identifier before '*' token
```

and when I call the constructor should I call like this?
ShortestPath(Graph);

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you must change your code as this way:

```
class ShortestPath{
public:
    ShortestPath(Graph& graph): graph(graph){};[...]
private:
    Graph &graph; 
}
```

or:

```
 class ShortestPath{
public:
    ShortestPath(Graph& graph): graph(&graph){};[...]
private:
    Graph *graph; 
}
```

Comment: You should add why, as it is more important than how.

Comment: when you use ShortestPath(Graph& graph): graph(graph) you are passing a Graph not a Graph * ( although it is a reference to your object and not a copy of it).    and when you use :ShortestPath(Graph& graph): *graph(graph){} it is syntactically false because your pointer is before your constructor instead of object.

Answer (score 3):

Two possible solutions:

Pass the graph by reference and store the pointer

```
// note that (&graph) gets the address of the graph
ShortestPath(Graph& graph): graph(&graph) {};
```

Pass the graph by pointer and store the pointer

```
ShortestPath(Graph* graph): graph(graph) {};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your `graph` is a pointer to a `Graph` you should use below way (as another answers):

```
ShortestPath(Graph& graph): graph(&graph) {};
                                  ^ // Get the pointer to object
```

But, if you're sure that the lifetime of passed `graph` is greater and equal to the lifetime of `ShortestPath`'s object. You can use references instead of pointers:

```
class ShortestPath{
    public:
        ShortestPath(Graph& graph): graph(graph){};

    private:
        Graph &graph; 
              ^ // A reference to object
};
```

Comment: What is the advantage of this second way?

Comment: @giacomotb: It'd better to avoid pointer base solution rather than non-pointer if you can. References can't refer to null. So, I personally prefer to use referencing way and get rid of those `->` ways.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the address of the Graph object, like this:

```
class ShortestPath{
    public:
        ShortestPath(Graph& graph): graph(&graph){}
    private:
        Graph *graph; 
};
```

Comment: Why not create a reference to the object in your private member variable instead of a pointer?

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg: That is certainly possible, and depending on the use case, may be preferable. It may be undesirable if `graph` could be null, such as having a default constructor with nothing to initialize it to.

Comment: True, but in most cases in C++. With normal classes, I hope people will use the reference, since this avoids you to use null pointers indeed. Maybe make a small note below your answer? That `Graph& graph`; is also fine. In that case the assessment will be: `graph(graph)`